# Проблема с установка Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu

Здравствуйте, проблема при установки, установка обычная устанавливаю не в первый раз на работе, И решил установить домой, но сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой[image: линк 1][image: линк 2]Что это такое? Как исправить? При этом меню не активное, ничего не клацается

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас Ubuntu 13.04 то там по умолчанию вообще unity (её мы и видим на Вашем фото) а не kde. Попробуйте обратиться на форум forum.ubuntu.ru

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте локальные скрипты загрузки! Это где-то там.

Comment: Можно ещё  снести весь конфиг Гнома, но где он, я там не знаю, у меня KDE.

Comment: А это где такое? я ведь только перешел на убунту :)